# Return with no value

Tags: c, obfuscation, c89

If I have an int function, with a `return;`

```
int f(int val, int *hasResult) {
  if (val) {
    *hasResult = 0;
    return;
  }
  *hasResult = 1;
  return 2;
}
```

and use it as

```
int hasResult;
int unwrapped = f(val, &hasResult);
if (hasResult) {
  printf("%d", unwrapped);
}
```

Is this valid C89? I know it's not valid C99+, but can I do this, exactly as it is, in C89? If not, how would I have to do this?

(`f` doesn't have side-effects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [C89 draft paragraph 3.6.6.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.6.6.4) we find:

> If a return statement without an expression is executed, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, **the behavior is undefined**. Reaching the } that terminates a function is equivalent to executing a return statement without an expression.

In short, to be avoided, whether "legal"or not.

Comment: What counts as use?

Comment: @SoniEx2: I don't think the Standard is 100% clear on that, but I think the intended meaning was probably close to "doing anything with the return value that might cause the target platform to do something weird".  C89 was written longer after C was already in wide use, and the most common meaning for most kinds of UB was "behave in a documented fashion characteristic of the environment".  With "modern" compilers, however, something like `int foo()  {... return bar();}` would be considered as "using" the value of `foo` whether or not the platform would offer any reason for it to do so.

Comment: What do ppl use for obfuscation in modern compilers?

Comment: @SoniEx2 what do you mean by "obfuscation" ?? In my book that's intentionally making something unreadable. The code you show is pretty readable so I'm wondering.

Comment: Only because I used some helpful names. If you had a, b, c instead of unwrapped, val, hasResult, it'd be fairly unreadable.

Comment: @SoniEx2 Regardless of the variable names, the point of the question was that the return without expression leads to UB, and I fail to see the relation between that and obfuscation.